# Heroku RAM not increasing with upgraded dynos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, memory, heroku

I have a massive function i have been calling manually through the heroku rails console.  I have been receiving the error rapid fire in my logs:

```
2015-06-22T14:56:42.940517+00:00 heroku[run.9877]: Process running mem=575M(112.4%)
2015-06-22T14:56:42.940517+00:00 heroku[run.9877]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

A 1X dyno is suppose to have 512 MB of RAM. I upgraded my dynos to 2X under the impression that it would double my RAM.  I restarted my dynos and am still receiving the R14 error.  Does it take more than an hour for the new dyno parameters to "kick in"? Can someone explain what i am missing?

Thank you
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow - have you tried asking heroku support? They're probably much better able to answer this question than we are...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That log excert is from a one off dyno, a la `heroku run console` - this is entirely seperate to your web dynos which you may be runnning 2x dyno's for. You need to specifiy `--size=2x` in your `heroku run` command to have the one off process use 2x dynos.